# Haskell slow to compute Ackermann 4 1?

Tags: haskell, ghc, ackermann

Here's an old question from 7 months ago, when stack overflowers agreed that Haskell's inefficiency in computing the Ackermann function was due to a compiler error.

[Ackermann very inefficient with Haskell/GHC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16115815/ackermann-very-inefficient-with-haskell-ghc)

7 months later, this appears to be fixed. It seems like ack runs with linear memory, but it runs pretty freakin' slow.

```
main = print (ack 4 1)
-- Ackermann function
ack 0 n = n + 1
ack m 0 = ack (m-1) 1
ack m n = ack (m-1) (ack m (n - 1))

$ time ./ack
65533

>real   8m53.274s
>user   8m47.313s
>sys    0m4.868s


Processor  2.8 GHz Intel Core i7
Memory  8 GB 1333 MHz DDR3
Software  Mac OS X Lion 10.7.5 (11G63)
```

I am just asking for any insights into this. The more detailed ones will get upvoted. Keep in mind I am new to functional programming and even simple remarks about tail recursion vs regular recursion would be appreciated and upvoted.

Comment: Do the timings change when you annotate `ack :: Int -> Int -> Int`

Comment: I thought the annotations were just for the programmer, and it would infer type regardless?

Comment: Sure, but it makes a difference whether the function is just for Int or for any number.

Comment: @BretFontecchio If you don't specify a type signature, it defaults to variable length `Integer`s, which are much slower than fixed size `Int`.

Comment: It did in fact speed it up by the way. "real 3m38.111s"

Comment: It should go at least 20 times faster ....

Comment: @LambdaFairy Worse, it probably infers `ack :: Num a => a -> a -> a`

Comment: @Ingo Yeah, you're right. I just remembered the monomorphism restriction doesn't apply to function declarations P:

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, where's 20 come from? It seems to take 1/3 as long.

Comment: I would be interested in hearing about the running time complexity of the Hindley Milner implementation in Haskell. I read somewhere it is DEXP-hard, but I'm sure what would plug in where. What is n? The number of variables, the number of types, and so on...

Comment: @BretFontecchio On my meager Intel Core i3, above program runs in 9.003s when compiled by Frege, which is basically a Haskell dialect for the JVM. I did think that GHC could do better, but since Thomas M DuBuisson reported 15.5s with ghc -O2 I assume that the JIT has a good opportunity to shine in this case.

Comment: I must still be doing something wrong. I'm getting ~4 min with -O2 and there are no warnings in -Wall

Comment: @BretFontecchio Are you using GHC 7.6.3?  Does your code include the type signatures?  4m is what I'd expect with `Integer` and `-O2`.

Comment: hmm I'm not at my computer right now but it is extremely recent. I downloaded Haskell platform about 4 days ago. I am almost positive I have "Int" although I can't double check until 930 when I get out of lecture. Oh and -fllvm knocked 30 seconds off.

Comment: OK I snuck over to my laptop and checked. I have the type annotation ack :: Int -> Int -> Int

Comment: Is this bug really fixed in the latest Haskell platform? I have GHC 7.6.3 here (OS X 10.9, 2.5GHz i5) and ack (with Ints and -fllvm) uses a large amount of memory (gigs) and takes 40 seconds to run. Increasing the stack chunk size (compile with "-O2 -fllvm -rtsopts" and run "time ./Ackermann +RTS -kc1M"), as suggested in the old Stack Overflow post, results in a total time of 4.8 seconds. Could someone with GHC 7.8 try this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know how you're running it, but I suspect the complete list is:

1. Your program with no changes and compiling with no optimizations. Initial time: **7m29.755s**
2. It appears you didn't use optimization.  Be sure to use `-O2` and try `-fllvm` when compiling. New time: **1m2.412s**
3. Use explicit type signatures and use `Int` (vs the default of `Integer`) when you can.  New time: **0m15.486s**

So we received almost 8x speed-up by using optimizations (why does every other benchmark question not use optimization flags?!?!?) and an additional ~4x by using `Int` instead of `Integer`.

Comment: That's still almost a factor of 10 worse than ajhc, so I still think it's a performance bug.

Comment: Compiler version might be relevant for this question

Comment: I'm using version 7.6.3

Answer (score 2):

Add a type signature to `ack`:

```
ack :: Int -> Int -> Int
```

This should solve two problems with your code:

### Overly general types

Without the signature, the compiler derives the following type:

```
ack :: (Eq a, Eq b, Num a, Num b) => a -> b -> b
```

`ack` ends up generalized to *all* number types, instead of just integers. This additional layer of indirection makes the code slow.

Giving `ack` a concrete type (like `Int`) removes this indirection.

### Type defaulting

In addition, I'm guessing your main action is written like this:

```
main = print (ack 4 1)
```

Your `ack` works on any number type, but you don't specify exactly which one. This means GHC chooses one automatically, in a process called *type defaulting*.

In this case, it chooses `Integer`, a variable length type. Because `Integer` can handle numbers of arbitrary size, it is much slower than the machine sized `Int`.

### Conclusion

To summarize:

- Always write type signatures for top-level definitions.
- Always compile with `-Wall`.

Comment: But if there's any function that requires Big `Integers`, it's Ackermann, isn't it?

Comment: Conveniently, Integer is not needed for this value of Ackermann.  Also, the first (very frustrating) issue is actually lack of optimization and not types.

Comment: I understand it's frustrating when many people make the same mistake, but it goes to show that it's an easy mistake to make, does it not? I do appreciate the patience though.

Comment: @BretFontecchio You have a point, I admit.  I am confused about _why_ the mistake is easy to make.  No one runs gcc without -O3 and expects top-notch performance.  Perhaps people have a (bad) mental connection between higher level languages and bytecode-centered languages that lean on JIT for optimizations?

Comment: I normally code java in an ide with an ant build.xml that don't really update too often. can't speak for everyone but this seems common.