# Is there a mathematics-related namspace in .net?

Tags: c#-4.0

Is there a math-related namespace in .Net?

In particular, I'm looking for information/classes to support working with algebra, trigonometry and geometry.

Comment: Have you tried looking at `System.Math`?

Answer (score 2):

[`System.Math`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.aspx) (It's a class, not a namespace)

...and yes, they will definitely help you develop a Windows Application that uses Algebra, Trigonometry, and Geometry.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in the [Math.NET](http://www.mathdotnet.com/) project. It's a mathematical opensource toolkit written in C# for the Microsoft .Net platform.

Answer (score 0):

There is `System.Math` class which is very basic.
Have a look at F# and there are many efforts recently in that area:

[Is F# really better than C# for math?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/379722/is-f-really-better-than-c-for-math)